# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase'

Tags: python, firebase

Hi i already installed both of this

```
!pip3 install python-firebase
!pip3 install firebase
```

through jupyterlab but the following error still happens:

> ```sh
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase'
> ```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Python is active for you? (`python --version`)

Comment: I used this version Python 3.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `python -m pip install python-firebase`? hope it will work!

Comment: I have done this but another error (**ImportError: cannot import name 'firebase' from 'firebase'**) happened when I want to use **from firebase import firebase**

Comment: Make sure you don't have any file called firebase.py.

Comment: Hi. I think you should update firebase rules as follows.

Go to in Firebase Console > Database >Rules and change  and set them to  ` ".read": "auth != null",
 ".write": "auth != null"

Comment: Awww, thanks a lot. You helped me to settle up my project :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

Then:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to import the firebase package in my project.

There are no files that name as firebase.py or anything related.
I have created a new project and imported the same package in the hello world programme, still gave me that error.
Just downgraded the firebase version to any (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.2.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1) and It will work.
I had the issue on 3.0.1, 3.0.0 versions and 2.2.0 worked for me.
you can try one by one and it will work